# Blazor unable to use class function

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

Im new to blazor and I have created a blazor app to create a UI for my enigma machine that i first created using a console app.
I have moved to class to the blazor app like this:

[image]

now within my page i have added this:

```
@page "/"
@using BlazorEngimaWeb.EnigmaModel
@inject Enigma enigma

<PageTitle>Engima</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

@code{
    
    char letter = enigma.Encrypt('H');
    
}
```

however, im unable to use the `enigma.Encrypt('H');`  as it says: `A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Home.enigma` 
Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Thanks

edit:
this is the engima class:

```
namespace BlazorEngimaWeb.EnigmaModel
{
    public class Enigma
    {
        Rotar rotarI = new ([8, 2, 12, 5, 18, 10, 3, 15, 20, 25, 13, 19, 14, 22, 24, 7, 23, 21, 9, 16, 0, 4, 1, 17, 6, 11], 10, 5);
        Rotar rotarII = new ([5, 1, 15, 7, 2, 11, 17, 14, 9, 0, 18, 12, 16, 24, 23, 20, 8, 25, 22, 19, 6, 21, 10, 3, 13, 4], 0, 19);
        Rotar rotarIII = new ([15, 4, 25, 20, 14, 7, 23, 18, 2, 21, 5, 12, 19, 1, 6, 11, 17, 8, 13, 16, 0, 24, 22, 10, 3, 9], 5, 8);
        Rotar rotarIV = new ([25, 14, 20, 4, 18, 24, 3, 10, 5, 22, 15, 2, 8, 16, 23, 7, 12, 21, 1, 11, 6, 13, 9, 17, 0, 19], 17, 22);
        Rotar rotarV = new ([22, 26, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 24, 6, 25, 11, 23, 7, 8, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 15, 20);

        Reflector reflectorB = new ([24, 17, 20, 7, 16, 18, 11, 3, 15, 23, 13, 6, 14, 10, 12, 8, 4, 1, 5, 25, 2, 22, 21, 9, 0, 19]);
        Plugboard plugboard = new();
        
        public char Encrypt(char letter)
        {
           letter = plugboard.Process(letter);
            rotarI.Rotate();
            letter = rotarI.Encrypt(letter);
            if (rotarI.IsAtNotch())
            {
                rotarII.Rotate();
            }
            letter = rotarII.Encrypt(letter);
            if (rotarII.IsAtNotch())
            {
                rotarIII.Rotate();
            }
            letter = rotarIII.Encrypt(letter);
            letter = reflectorB.Reflect(letter);
            letter = rotarIII.Encrypt(letter, true);
            letter = rotarII.Encrypt(letter, true);
            letter = rotarI.Encrypt(letter, true);
            letter = plugboard.Process(letter);
            return letter;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are a couple of issues with the approach you have taken. Can you post the code for your Enigma class to help fix the problem.

Comment: Hi i updated to question with the code

Answer (score 1):

```
@code{
    
   char letter = '?';

   protected override void OnInitialized()
   {
     letter = enigma.Encrypt('H');
   }
    
}
```

Comment: that worked, if you can, can you explain why it has to be in the OnInitialized? Thanks

Comment: Nothing to do with Blazor, plain C# rules.  You can't call code in a member var declaration.